# Can in_array() compare to the first value of all second-level arrays of a two-dimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to find a simpler solution for this particular situation:

1. I have a one-dimensional array (`$array1`) without keys, containing about 400 values (strings)
2. Then I am fetching data from a database (using a prepared statement), 4 values per row, which I use to create a two-dimensional array (`$array2a`) which I need later.
3. Now I want to compare the values of `$array1` to the values in the first row of `$array2a`: I want to create a list of all values of `$array1` which are *not* in the first row of the database (field "username").

I found a working solution, but it seems to be a bit too complicated - it uses two different arrays in step #2, one containing only the strings to be compared to array1, the other one containing all 4 values fetched from the database which I need later:

```
/* $array1 exists already */

$array2a = array();
$array2b = array();

/*  "$db" already contains the code for the database connection */
if($ps = $db->prepare("SELECT username, value2, value3, value4 FROM userlist")) {
    $ps->execute();
    $ps->bind_result($username, $value2, $value3, $value4);
    while($ps->fetch()) {
        $array2a[] = array($username, $value2, $value3, $value4);
        $array2b[] = $username;
    }
    $ps->free_result();
}
$db->close;

/* comparison of $array1 to $array2b: */
foreach($array1 as $x) {
    if(!in_array($x, $array2b)) {
        echo $x."<br>";
    }
}
```

This gives me a list of all values of `$array1` which are *not* in the `username` column of the database. However, in the second part (the `foreach` loop) I'd like to use `$array2a` instead of `$array2b`, but I don't know how to apply the `in_array()` function to only each first value of the second-level arrays of `$array2a`. I tried to use `if(!in_array($x, $array2a[0])) { ... }`, but that doesn't work of course...

Comment: Not sure if I understood correctly, but why not use `where username in (/* values of array1*/)`? And then use `array_diff()`;

Comment: You could skip the creation of `$array2b` and run a diff against `array_column($array2a, 0)`

Comment: @FelippeDuarte Well, I need *all* data records of that table in array2 for another comparison that follows immediately after this. I could do what you wrote and add another database query but that would as well be another step which I'd like to avoid.

Comment: You can also use `->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM)` instead of loop with `->fetch()`

Comment: @FelippeDuarte Judging by the use of `bind_result()` I'd guess OP is using `mysqli`. In that case, it would be `->fetch_all(MYSQLI_NUM)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array_column()` to quickly get a list of all usernames returned by your database. Then, as @FelippeDuarte suggested, you could use `array_diff()` to quickly get all usernames from `$array1` that are not in your database result:

```
// example data set
$array1 = ['bob', 'john', 'mary', 'elizabeth'];
$array2a = [
    ['bob', 2, 3, 4],
    ['mary', 2, 3, 4]
];

$usernamesFromDatabase = array_column($array2a, 0);  // ['bob', 'mary']
$usernamesNotInDatabase = array_diff($array1, $usernamesFromDatabase);

print_r($usernamesNotInDatabase);
/*
Array
(
    [1] => john
    [3] => elizabeth
)
*/
```

Note that the array indices from `$array1` are kept using `array_diff()`. If that's a problem, you can reset the indices using `array_values()`:

```
$resetIndices = array_values($usernamesNotInDatabase);
print_r($resetIndices);
/*
Array
(
    [0] => john
    [1] => elizabeth
)
*/
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped me to get it working! I I actually stayed closer to my original code: I used `if(!in_array($x, array_column($array2a, 0))) { echo ... }`, which worked as well.