# in_array() always returns false?

Tags: php, arrays

`in_array('test',$_SESSION['userPermissions'])` returns `false`

`print_r($_SESSION['userPermissions'])` returns:

```
    Array(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [permission_name] => Admin
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [permission_name] => test
        )

)
```

Why does in_array not return true? I also tried 'Admin' or "Admin" or "test".

Comment: I got a useful answer to a similar question a while ago here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60046924/5641669

Answer (score 2):

Your array is a *nested array*. It's an array *inside* an array. So you have to refer to as a nested array:

```
echo $_SESSION['userPermissions'][0]['permission_name'];
// output: "Admin"

echo $_SESSION['userPermissions'][1]['permission_name'];
// output: "test"
```

Since you are looking for a permission named "test" your best bet is to get all of those permissions into an array and *then* use `in_array()`. You can use [`array_column()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to get all of the values with a name of "permission_name" and put them into an array. Then `in_array()` will work as you expect:

```
$permissions = array_column($_SESSION, 'permission_name');
if (in_array('test', $permissions, true)) {
    echo 'Found it';
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/bHo1m)